# How to detect if a boost thread is currently running?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell reliably if a boost thread has exited its run method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667420/how-can-i-tell-reliably-if-a-boost-thread-has-exited-its-run-method)

I would like to detect if a boost thread is running.

It seems that `joinable()` function does the stuff, am I right or is there any better way to do that ?

Thanks.

PS : I want to avoid the use of a boolean managed by me.