# Boost thread, how can I check if a thread is still running?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am using boost::thread, how can I tell if a thread is still running from another thread?

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty much this question, right?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667420/how-can-i-tell-reliably-if-a-boost-thread-has-exited-its-run-method Except you have to put the thread you want to check as reference/pointer argument to the other thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer would be that you can't, but if you just want to check so as to avoid blocking in `join`, there's a `timed_join` function.