# how to join thread if joinable do nothing otherwise?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using `boost::thread join` method to wait until thread is finished. But if I try to `join` the thread when it already finished I receive an exception. So how can I:

Join thread if active and do nothing if not active?

Comment: this thread may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667420/how-can-i-tell-reliably-if-a-boost-thread-has-exited-its-run-method

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing else going on? In the manual it says that `If the thread of execution represented by the boost::thread object has already completed, or the boost::thread object represents Not-a-Thread, then join() returns immediately.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `joinable()` function to check whether it should be joined:

```
if (thread.joinable()) thread.join();
```

You can (in fact, you must) join a thread even if it's already finished, unless it's been detached. It's an error to join it twice, or to join an empty or detached thread.

Comment: thanks! i assume `if (thread.joinable()) thread.join();` is not atomic operation so.. very unlikely but still possible to receive an exception?

Comment: @javapowered: No, there should be no exception unless you join it twice. It doesn't matter whether the other thread has finished by the time you call `join` - it needs to be joined anyway. (Of course, you will have a race if two threads both try to join it in this way; but that would be an insane design).

Comment: To make it explicit: `joinable()` returns true if the thread has not been joined and has not been detached. Both of those are global actions, and should not be done in a context where a race is possible.