# Boost thread finished callback available

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, callback

I am looking for a way to call a callback function when a boost thread (boost version 1.60, ordinary thread, no thread group or pool) finishes. I have read this

[How can I tell reliably if a boost thread has exited its run method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667420/how-can-i-tell-reliably-if-a-boost-thread-has-exited-its-run-method)

but I need some kind of callback. Any idea how to do this? Do I have to create some kind of a conditional variable?

Thanks for help!

Comment: There is no callback defined on `boost::thread` finishing. Instead, you could join the thread and than call whatever callback you want yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guessed so. I think I will finally go with that or either create a conditional variable. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the problem?  If you want to know when a thread is finishing by callback, have it call your callback thing as its last line before exiting.

Comment: Two other threads are waiting for an intermediate result, that is the situation. I decided for the condVar solution. Easy to implement and works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to wrap your original thread function:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void callback()
{
    std::cout << "callback invoked" << std::endl;
}

void orig_thread_func()
{
    std::cout << "thread function invoked" << std::endl;
}

void wrapper(void (*func)())
{
    func();        // invoke your original thread function
    callback();    // invoke callback
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread t(&wrapper, &orig_thread_func);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need a interface like `atexit` which register callback on process exit.

So Using `at_thread_exit`, see [this_thread.atthreadexit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.atthreadexit)

Usage:

```
void thread_exit_callback(){
  std::cout <<"thread exit now!" <<std::endl;
}

void thread_func(){  
  boost::this_thread::at_thread_exit(thread_exit_callback);
}

int main() {
  boost::thread t(thread_func);
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seriously? Answering this question nearly three years after it was posted? Meanwhile I won't even use Boost any longer for threads, considering c++ 17 features...

Comment: You didn't update your question that you no longer use `boost::thread`. Perhaps someone else has the same question.